# Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, and $\forall x\in X, \{y\in X:y>x\}$ is countable. Prove $X$ is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, cardinals

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, and $\forall x\in X, \{y\in X:y>x\}$ is countable.

Prove $X$ is countable.

I was trying to use that if $X$ is uncountable, it embeds into $\omega_1^*$ which is a contradiction,
but I don't know how to show this embedding.

Comment: Write $X$ as a countable union of upper segments.

Comment: What about expressing $X$ as a countable union of countable sets?

Comment: But how do you know there are countably many lower segments

Comment: One thing you could try is to construct a decreasing sequence of elements of $X$, which are unbounded from below in $X$, i.e. if $X$ is bounded from below in $\mathbb{R}$, choose a sequence which is convergent to $\inf X$ or if $X$ is unbounded, choose a sequence with limit $-\infty$. Now you can use these to show $X$ is the union of countably many countable sets.

Comment: Also if you want to go with the embedding route, you can construct an embedding from $\omega_1^*$ into $X$, by recursion. The hypothesis on $X$ and the uncountability of $X$, will assure that you can keep going with the recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Split the problem in two cases:

**Case 1**  $X$ is bounded from below.

Let $a= \inf(X)$. If $a \in X$ the claim is obvious. If $a \notin X$ then for each $n$ tehre exists some $a<a_n <a+\frac{1}{n}$.

Show that 
$$X= \bigcup_n \{y\in X:y>a_n\}$$

**Case 2:** $X$ is unbounded from below. For each $n$ pick some $a_n \in X$ such that $a_n <-n$.

Show that 
$$X= \bigcup_n \{y\in X:y>a_n\}$$

Comment: This is correct, but shouldn't it be $a_n<-n$ for case 2 since we need an infinite decreasing sequence?

Comment: @JamesGwin Thank you, fixed.

Comment: You can combine both cases by fixing a decreasing sequence $a_n$ with $a_n\to\inf(X)$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I think you need it non-increasing to cover the case $\inf(X) \in X$. But good point.

Comment: Yes, that's how I use the term. :-)